# convert string of objects to list of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string

```
"{'first': '292759', 'second': '35%', 'third': '28.53 DT', 'fourth': '15', 'fifth': '427.95DT', 'sixth': '577.7325DT'", " {'first': '13607', 'second': '50%', 'third': '42.88 DT', 'fourth': '3', 'fifth': '128.64DT', 'sixth': '192.96DT'", " {'first': '720218', 'second': '40 %', 'third': '47.69DT', 'fourth': '12', 'fifth': '572.28DT', 'sixth': '801.192DT'}"
```

and I want to turn it to a list of objects like this:

```
[{"first": "292759", "second': "35%", "third": "28.53 DT", "fourth": "15", "fifth": "427.95DT", "sixth": "577.7325DT", {"first": "13607", "second": "50%", "third": "42.88" DT", "fourth": "3", "fifth": "128.64DT", "sixth": "192.96DT", {"first": "720218", "second": "40 %", "third": "47.69DT", "fourth": "12", "fifth": "572.28DT", "sixth": "801.192DT"}]
```

I tried to replace all single quotes with double quotes but elements inside my array were in this format "string" , any ideas ?

Comment: try `JSON.parse('['+string+']')`

Comment: Do you want each entry to be an object like `[{first: "292759"}, {second: "35%"}]` or for everything to be a single entry in the array `[{first: "292759", second: "35%"}]` ?

Comment: the second choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll just have to massage the string a bit to get it to be valid json:

```js
const str = `"{'first': '292759', 'second': '35%', 'third': '28.53 DT', 'fourth': '15', 'fifth': '427.95DT', 'sixth': '577.7325DT'", " {'first': '13607', 'second': '50%', 'third': '42.88 DT', 'fourth': '3', 'fifth': '128.64DT', 'sixth': '192.96DT'", " {'first': '720218', 'second': '40 %', 'third': '47.69DT', 'fourth': '12', 'fifth': '572.28DT', 'sixth': '801.192DT'}"`

console.log(JSON.parse('[' + str + ']').map((el) => {
    if (!el.endsWith('}')) el = el + '}';
    return JSON.parse(el.split("'").join('"'));
}))
```

Comment: it worked but how can I add "`" at the beginning and the end of a variable ?

Comment: it doesn't work with this example too : `"{'first': '533823', 'second': '25%', 'third': '50.07 DT', 'fourth': '8', 'fifth': '400.56DT', 'sixth': '500.70DT'}, {'first': '418330', 'second': '40 %', 'third': '76.41 DT', 'fourth': '9', 'fifth': '687.69DT', 'sixth': '962.766DT'}, {'first': '438963', 'second': '30%', 'third': '32.77DT', 'fourth': '163.85DT', 'fifth': '213.005DT'}, {'first': '946039', 'second': '25%', 'third': '72.71DT', 'fourth': '13', 'fifth': '945.23DT', 'sixth': '1181.5375DT'}"`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your initial strings are attempting to be JSON, however they are not quite valid.
Do you have any control over the initial formatting of the strings themselves? If so you can use JSON.parse (see [mdn documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse))

```js
const my_object = JSON.parse(strings);
```

However to be able to do that you'll have to format your strings to valid json first.

That means double quotes around keys and values, closing braces and wrapping the whole thing in an array.

For instance

```js
'[{"first": "value", "second": "23%"}, {"first": "value", "second": "43%"}]'
```